# Зависает соединение с БД на Python

Tags: python, sql

Очень простой код

```
import fdb 
import os 
import shutil 
import glob

dbname = 'D:\Project\2014\testdb\MAINDB.FDB' 
conn = fdb.connect(dbname, user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

cursor = conn.cursor()

dst = "D:\1"

def copyfiles(src): 
    print "src = %s" % src 
    print "dst = %s" % dst 
    print "=======================" 
    if os.path.exists(dst): 
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src): 
            print filenames 
        return True 
    else: 
        print "FOLDER DO NOT EXIST" 
        return False

def doit(): 
    cursor.execute("select ROUTE_ID, FILE_NAME, FL_ARCHIVE FROM ROUTE where FL_ARCHIVE  = %s;" % (10))#.fetchall() 
    select_result = cursor.fetchall() 
    for id, name, fl in select_result: 
        name = os.path.dirname(name) 
        if copyfiles(name): 
            cursor.execute("UPDATE ROUTE SET FL_ARCHIVE = %s WHERE ROUTE_ID=%s;" % (11, id)) 
            conn.commit() 
            print "value changed"

        else: 
            cursor.execute("UPDATE ROUTE SET FL_ARCHIVE = %s WHERE ROUTE_ID=%s;" % (13, id)) 
            conn.commit() 
            print "value DO NOT changed" 
conn.close()     
doit()
```

проблема в том, что стоит обернуть код работающий с БД в функцию `def doit()`, как он программа сразу начинает зависать. В чем может быть причина? Я соединение там где нужно закрываю или нет?

Comment: > Я соединение там где нужно закрываю или нет?

Нет, конечно. Функция пытается использовать закрытое соединение.

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к БД должно быть до закрытия соединения, а у Вас наоборот функция вызывается после закрытия. Поменяйте местами conn.close() и doit().

Comment: Убрал функцию и закрытие соединения, однако код теперь зависает на 31 строке.
http://nopaste.info/ac07096d2e.html

Не могу понять почему. Вроде все вернул как было.

Comment: @Suliman3, скорее всего сервак БД поддерживает только одно подключение от одного аккаунта.